# Bash Shell scripting - User input

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I am new to Shell scripting.

Can anyone tell me what should I do in the script below, so that instead of taking the date/time as a parameter for git commit, it actually prompts me to enter the comment ?

```
#!/bin/bash

TODAY=$(date)
.............
.............
git commit -m "$TODAY"
............
............
```

Comment: `man bash` and search for `read`.

Comment: Thanks for teaching to fish :)

Comment: @KingsIndian or simply `help read`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
read -p "Comment: " comment
git commit -m "$comment"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Type the date, followed by [ENTER]:"

read TODAY
git commit -m "$TODAY"
```